# NLog doesn't log anything when programmatically setting XmlLoggingConfiguration

Tags: c#, nlog

This is with NLog version 4.0.1 for C# .NET.

So I have what I think is a rather unique problem where I cannot use the standard config file locations for NLog in order to load a configuration xml file. The only solution that would work in my case is having a registry key that holds the NLog.config (the xml configuration file) location, and when NLog is loaded, the registry key must be read so NLog knows where to find the configuration file. This configuration loading works great as you can see from the TRACE level internal log file I have generated below. The problem is, when I run the program and try to do any kind of logging, no actual logging occurs beyond the internal logging.

I've noticed no errors get logged at the internal log level, and no exceptions being thrown in my program, so there's no obvious issues there. The only thing I can think of is NLog doesn't like the config being manually set like this? Any help or solution would be greatly appreciated.

Below is a snippet of the base class where the logger is defined with a quick example of how it is used.

```
public class MyBaseClass
{
    private ILog _Logger = null;
    public ILog Logger
    {
        get
        {
            if(_Logger == null)
            {
                RegistryKey rk = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("Software\\SomeRegistryLocation\\Configuration", false);
                NLog.LogManager.Configuration = new NLog.Config.XmlLoggingConfiguration((string)rk.GetValue("NLogConfigFile"), true);
                _Logger = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(MyBaseClass));
            }
            return _Logger;
        }
    }

    public void SomeMethod()
    {
        Logger.Info("Hello, is this working?");
    }
}
```

Here is the NLog.config xml.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<nlog internalLogFile="C:\NLog\NLog_Internal.txt" 
      internalLogLevel="trace"
      internalLogToConsole="true"
      xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      autoReload="true">
  <extensions>
    <add assembly="Something.NLogExtension, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=asdfasdfasdfasdf" />
    <!-- query-string layout renderer can be found here -->
  </extensions>

  <targets>
      <target xsi:type="File" name="logfile" fileName="C:\NLog\Test_Log.txt" layout="${longdate} ${logger} [${level}] - ${message}"/>
  </targets>
  <rules>
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="logfile"/>
  </rules>
</nlog>
```

And here is the output of the NLog internal logging when I try to run my program. Notice that it contains no errors.

```
2018-03-06 14:46:08.7653 Info Loading assembly name: Something.NLogExtension, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=asdfasdfasdfasdf
2018-03-06 14:46:08.7734 Debug ScanAssembly('Something.NLogExtension, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=asdfasdfasdfasdf')
2018-03-06 14:46:08.7995 Trace FindReachableObject<NLog.Internal.IRenderable>:
2018-03-06 14:46:08.8094 Trace Scanning LongDateLayoutRenderer 'Layout Renderer: ${longdate}'
2018-03-06 14:46:08.8196 Debug Setting 'UppercaseLayoutRendererWrapper.uppercase' to 'true'
2018-03-06 14:46:08.8196 Trace Wrapping LevelLayoutRenderer with UppercaseLayoutRendererWrapper
2018-03-06 14:46:08.8326 Trace FindReachableObject<NLog.Internal.IRenderable>:
2018-03-06 14:46:08.8326 Trace Scanning LevelLayoutRenderer 'Layout Renderer: ${level}'
2018-03-06 14:46:08.8326 Trace FindReachableObject<NLog.Internal.IRenderable>:
2018-03-06 14:46:08.8473 Trace Scanning UppercaseLayoutRendererWrapper 'Layout Renderer: ${uppercase}'
2018-03-06 14:46:08.8473 Trace  Scanning SimpleLayout ''''
2018-03-06 14:46:08.8473 Trace   Scanning LevelLayoutRenderer 'Layout Renderer: ${level}'
2018-03-06 14:46:08.8473 Trace FindReachableObject<NLog.Internal.IRenderable>:
2018-03-06 14:46:08.8637 Trace Scanning LoggerNameLayoutRenderer 'Layout Renderer: ${logger}'
2018-03-06 14:46:08.8637 Trace FindReachableObject<NLog.Internal.IRenderable>:
2018-03-06 14:46:08.8637 Trace Scanning MessageLayoutRenderer 'Layout Renderer: ${message}'
2018-03-06 14:46:08.8825 Debug Setting 'FileTarget.name' to 'logfile'
2018-03-06 14:46:08.8825 Debug Setting 'FileTarget.fileName' to 'C:\NLog\Test_Log.txt'
2018-03-06 14:46:08.8946 Debug Setting 'FileTarget.layout' to '${longdate} ${logger} [${level}] - ${message}'
2018-03-06 14:46:08.8946 Trace FindReachableObject<NLog.Internal.IRenderable>:
2018-03-06 14:46:08.8946 Trace Scanning LongDateLayoutRenderer 'Layout Renderer: ${longdate}'
2018-03-06 14:46:08.8946 Trace FindReachableObject<NLog.Internal.IRenderable>:
2018-03-06 14:46:08.9123 Trace Scanning LoggerNameLayoutRenderer 'Layout Renderer: ${logger}'
2018-03-06 14:46:08.9123 Trace FindReachableObject<NLog.Internal.IRenderable>:
2018-03-06 14:46:08.9123 Trace Scanning LevelLayoutRenderer 'Layout Renderer: ${level}'
2018-03-06 14:46:08.9123 Trace FindReachableObject<NLog.Internal.IRenderable>:
2018-03-06 14:46:08.9274 Trace Scanning MessageLayoutRenderer 'Layout Renderer: ${message}'
2018-03-06 14:46:08.9274 Info Adding target File Target[logfile]
2018-03-06 14:46:08.9274 Debug Registering target logfile: NLog.Targets.FileTarget
2018-03-06 14:46:08.9444 Trace ParseRulesElement
2018-03-06 14:46:08.9444 Info Configured from an XML element in C:\Program Files\Common Files\NLog\NLog.config...
2018-03-06 14:46:08.9615 Debug --- NLog configuration dump. ---
2018-03-06 14:46:08.9615 Debug Targets:
2018-03-06 14:46:08.9615 Info File Target[logfile]
2018-03-06 14:46:08.9754 Debug Rules:
2018-03-06 14:46:08.9754 Info logNamePattern: (:All) levels: [ Trace Debug Info Warn Error Fatal ] appendTo: [ logfile ]
2018-03-06 14:46:08.9754 Debug --- End of NLog configuration dump ---
2018-03-06 14:46:08.9915 Trace FindReachableObject<System.Object>:
2018-03-06 14:46:08.9915 Trace Scanning LoggingRule 'logNamePattern: (:All) levels: [ Trace Debug Info Warn Error Fatal ] appendTo: [ logfile ]'
2018-03-06 14:46:08.9915 Trace  Scanning FileTarget 'File Target[logfile]'
2018-03-06 14:46:09.0064 Trace   Scanning SimpleLayout ''C:\NLog\Test_Log.txt''
2018-03-06 14:46:09.0064 Trace    Scanning LiteralLayoutRenderer 'Layout Renderer: ${literal}'
2018-03-06 14:46:09.0218 Trace   Scanning SimpleLayout ''${longdate} ${logger} [${level}] - ${message}''
2018-03-06 14:46:09.0218 Trace    Scanning LongDateLayoutRenderer 'Layout Renderer: ${longdate}'
2018-03-06 14:46:09.0396 Trace    Scanning LiteralLayoutRenderer 'Layout Renderer: ${literal}'
2018-03-06 14:46:09.0396 Trace    Scanning LoggerNameLayoutRenderer 'Layout Renderer: ${logger}'
2018-03-06 14:46:09.0396 Trace    Scanning LiteralLayoutRenderer 'Layout Renderer: ${literal}'
2018-03-06 14:46:09.0553 Trace    Scanning LevelLayoutRenderer 'Layout Renderer: ${level}'
2018-03-06 14:46:09.0553 Trace    Scanning LiteralLayoutRenderer 'Layout Renderer: ${literal}'
2018-03-06 14:46:09.0553 Trace    Scanning MessageLayoutRenderer 'Layout Renderer: ${message}'
2018-03-06 14:46:09.0734 Info Found 12 configuration items
2018-03-06 14:46:09.0848 Trace Initializing Layout Renderer: ${message}
2018-03-06 14:46:09.0848 Trace Initializing Layout Renderer: ${literal}
2018-03-06 14:46:09.0848 Trace Initializing Layout Renderer: ${level}
2018-03-06 14:46:09.1028 Trace Initializing Layout Renderer: ${literal}
2018-03-06 14:46:09.1028 Trace Initializing Layout Renderer: ${logger}
2018-03-06 14:46:09.1136 Trace Initializing Layout Renderer: ${literal}
2018-03-06 14:46:09.1136 Trace Initializing Layout Renderer: ${longdate}
2018-03-06 14:46:09.1136 Trace Initializing '${longdate} ${logger} [${level}] - ${message}'
2018-03-06 14:46:09.1136 Trace FindReachableObject<System.Object>:
2018-03-06 14:46:09.1356 Trace Scanning SimpleLayout ''${longdate} ${logger} [${level}] - ${message}''
2018-03-06 14:46:09.1356 Trace  Scanning LongDateLayoutRenderer 'Layout Renderer: ${longdate}'
2018-03-06 14:46:09.1503 Trace  Scanning LiteralLayoutRenderer 'Layout Renderer: ${literal}'
2018-03-06 14:46:09.1503 Trace  Scanning LoggerNameLayoutRenderer 'Layout Renderer: ${logger}'
2018-03-06 14:46:09.1503 Trace  Scanning LiteralLayoutRenderer 'Layout Renderer: ${literal}'
2018-03-06 14:46:09.1614 Trace  Scanning LevelLayoutRenderer 'Layout Renderer: ${level}'
2018-03-06 14:46:09.1614 Trace  Scanning LiteralLayoutRenderer 'Layout Renderer: ${literal}'
2018-03-06 14:46:09.1614 Trace  Scanning MessageLayoutRenderer 'Layout Renderer: ${message}'
2018-03-06 14:46:09.1846 Trace Initializing Layout Renderer: ${literal}
2018-03-06 14:46:09.1846 Trace Initializing 'C:\NLog\Test_Log.txt'
2018-03-06 14:46:09.1944 Trace FindReachableObject<System.Object>:
2018-03-06 14:46:09.1944 Trace Scanning SimpleLayout ''C:\NLog\Test_Log.txt''
2018-03-06 14:46:09.1944 Trace  Scanning LiteralLayoutRenderer 'Layout Renderer: ${literal}'
2018-03-06 14:46:09.2087 Trace Initializing File Target[logfile]
2018-03-06 14:46:09.2087 Trace FindReachableObject<NLog.Layouts.Layout>:
2018-03-06 14:46:09.2313 Trace Scanning FileTarget 'File Target[logfile]'
2018-03-06 14:46:09.2415 Trace  Scanning SimpleLayout ''C:\NLog\Test_Log.txt''
2018-03-06 14:46:09.2415 Trace   Scanning LiteralLayoutRenderer 'Layout Renderer: ${literal}'
2018-03-06 14:46:09.2415 Trace  Scanning SimpleLayout ''${longdate} ${logger} [${level}] - ${message}''
2018-03-06 14:46:09.2553 Trace   Scanning LongDateLayoutRenderer 'Layout Renderer: ${longdate}'
2018-03-06 14:46:09.2553 Trace   Scanning LiteralLayoutRenderer 'Layout Renderer: ${literal}'
2018-03-06 14:46:09.2553 Trace   Scanning LoggerNameLayoutRenderer 'Layout Renderer: ${logger}'
2018-03-06 14:46:09.2696 Trace   Scanning LiteralLayoutRenderer 'Layout Renderer: ${literal}'
2018-03-06 14:46:09.2696 Trace   Scanning LevelLayoutRenderer 'Layout Renderer: ${level}'
2018-03-06 14:46:09.2696 Trace   Scanning LiteralLayoutRenderer 'Layout Renderer: ${literal}'
2018-03-06 14:46:09.2863 Trace   Scanning MessageLayoutRenderer 'Layout Renderer: ${message}'
2018-03-06 14:46:09.2863 Trace File Target[logfile] has 2 layouts
2018-03-06 14:46:09.2863 Trace FindReachableObject<System.Object>:
2018-03-06 14:46:09.3024 Trace Scanning LoggingRule 'logNamePattern: (:All) levels: [ Trace Debug Info Warn Error Fatal ] appendTo: [ logfile ]'
2018-03-06 14:46:09.3024 Trace  Scanning FileTarget 'File Target[logfile]'
2018-03-06 14:46:09.3024 Trace   Scanning SimpleLayout ''C:\NLog\Test_Log.txt''
2018-03-06 14:46:09.3213 Trace    Scanning LiteralLayoutRenderer 'Layout Renderer: ${literal}'
2018-03-06 14:46:09.3213 Trace   Scanning SimpleLayout ''${longdate} ${logger} [${level}] - ${message}''
2018-03-06 14:46:09.3334 Trace    Scanning LongDateLayoutRenderer 'Layout Renderer: ${longdate}'
2018-03-06 14:46:09.3334 Trace    Scanning LiteralLayoutRenderer 'Layout Renderer: ${literal}'
2018-03-06 14:46:09.3334 Trace    Scanning LoggerNameLayoutRenderer 'Layout Renderer: ${logger}'
2018-03-06 14:46:09.3563 Trace    Scanning LiteralLayoutRenderer 'Layout Renderer: ${literal}'
2018-03-06 14:46:09.3563 Trace    Scanning LevelLayoutRenderer 'Layout Renderer: ${level}'
2018-03-06 14:46:09.3694 Trace    Scanning LiteralLayoutRenderer 'Layout Renderer: ${literal}'
2018-03-06 14:46:09.3694 Trace    Scanning MessageLayoutRenderer 'Layout Renderer: ${message}'
2018-03-06 14:46:09.3833 Info Found 12 configuration items
2018-03-06 14:46:09.3949 Trace Initializing Layout Renderer: ${message}
2018-03-06 14:46:09.3949 Trace Initializing Layout Renderer: ${literal}
2018-03-06 14:46:09.3949 Trace Initializing Layout Renderer: ${level}
2018-03-06 14:46:09.4195 Trace Initializing Layout Renderer: ${literal}
2018-03-06 14:46:09.4364 Trace Initializing Layout Renderer: ${logger}
2018-03-06 14:46:09.4476 Trace Initializing Layout Renderer: ${literal}
2018-03-06 14:46:09.4574 Trace Initializing Layout Renderer: ${longdate}
2018-03-06 14:46:09.4574 Trace Initializing '${longdate} ${logger} [${level}] - ${message}'
2018-03-06 14:46:09.4574 Trace Initializing Layout Renderer: ${literal}
2018-03-06 14:46:09.4735 Trace Initializing 'C:\NLog\Test_Log.txt'
2018-03-06 14:46:09.4735 Trace Initializing File Target[logfile]
2018-03-06 14:46:09.4735 Info Watching path 'C:\Program Files\Common Files\NLog' filter 'NLog.config' for changes.
2018-03-06 14:46:09.7739 Info Shutting down logging...
2018-03-06 14:46:09.7739 Info Stopping file watching for path 'C:\Program Files\Common Files\NLog' filter 'NLog.config'
2018-03-06 14:46:09.7739 Info Closing old configuration.
2018-03-06 14:46:09.7895 Trace LogFactory.Flush(00:00:15)
2018-03-06 14:46:09.7895 Trace Flushing all targets...
2018-03-06 14:46:09.8014 Trace ForEachItemInParallel() 1 items
2018-03-06 14:46:09.8014 Trace Continuation invoked: 
2018-03-06 14:46:09.8014 Trace Parallel task completed. 0 items remaining
2018-03-06 14:46:09.8247 Debug Closing logging configuration...
2018-03-06 14:46:09.8247 Trace Closing File Target[logfile]
2018-03-06 14:46:09.8395 Trace Closing 'C:\NLog\Test_Log.txt'
2018-03-06 14:46:09.8395 Trace Closing Layout Renderer: ${literal}
2018-03-06 14:46:09.8489 Trace Closing '${longdate} ${logger} [${level}] - ${message}'
2018-03-06 14:46:09.8489 Trace Closing Layout Renderer: ${longdate}
2018-03-06 14:46:09.8489 Trace Closing Layout Renderer: ${literal}
2018-03-06 14:46:09.8489 Trace Closing Layout Renderer: ${logger}
2018-03-06 14:46:09.8656 Trace Closing Layout Renderer: ${literal}
2018-03-06 14:46:09.8656 Trace Closing Layout Renderer: ${level}
2018-03-06 14:46:09.8656 Trace Closing Layout Renderer: ${literal}
2018-03-06 14:46:09.8824 Trace Closing Layout Renderer: ${message}
2018-03-06 14:46:09.8824 Debug Finished closing logging configuration.
2018-03-06 14:46:09.8824 Info Logger has been shut down.
```

Comment: This may be a dumb question, but are you actually calling `SomeMethod()` somewhere? I mocked up a project using your code, and it worked fine as long as I called that method (and I could see in the internal log that it was working). If I don't call 'SomeMethod()` I get an internal log that looks just like yours, and no actual logging.

Comment: Yes, SomeMethod() does get called from elsewhere in the project. I've confirmed with a Console.WriteLine() of the same text that I am trying to log just to verify. However if its working for you, that is...troublesome.

Comment: What about the `Info Shutting down logging..`? Is the program shutdown before writing the logs? You could add to the end of your program `NLog.LogManager.Shutdown();`, to flush all the messages

Comment: Yes, I tried using Nlog.LogManager.Shutdown() as well as NLog.LogManager.Flush() and neither seemed to work unfortunately.

Comment: @JoeBeck Please perform test with NLog 4.4.12 and NLog 4.5-rc07. NLog ver. 4.0.1 is not a good version.

Comment: I'll see what I can do about updating the version, as a lot of dependencies rely on 4.0.1, and updating is no easy feat. I will try to look for other solutions before going through with this.

Comment: @JoeBeck The strong version name is the same for NLog 4.0.1 and NLog 4.4.13 (or NLog 4.5-rc07). There should not be any breaking changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I found the solution. Updating NLog wasn't the solution unfortunately so after a lot more reading and investigating I realized I had configured NLog properly, but Common.Logging hadn't been configured at all. So when I was using the ILog interface to log the Info statement, nothing would happen because Common.Logging hadn't been configured properly.